# Changing email address on account

Tags: support

I created this account some years ago with a college gmail address. I ended up forgetting I had this account and made a new one through my current gmail address. But within the 1st week of using my new account I came across a question I had asked years ago. It was then I remembered I had my old account and logged in to revive it. I was hoping to mitigate it and change the email address on it to my new gmail account, but since I had already created an account for my new gmail it wouldn't let me change it. Is there anyway to mitigate the two accounts, or delete my account on my new gmail and change the email on my old college account to my current gmail?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield thanks, I just sent them a ticket.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield You should turn that into an answer.

Comment: I don't think "mitigate" is the word you were looking for, but I'm not sure exactly what you meant to say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts

Summary: Yes, it is possible to merge accounts, but the process is not automatic. Someone from Stack Exchange needs to verify that you own both accounts. You can get things going by picking "I need to merge user profiles" from the [Contact Us](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) link.

If all you want to do is change the email address associated with your account, you can add and remove login credentials from your user profile page by clicking on the "Logins" link:

[[image: New Layout Login Link]]
[[image: Old Layout Login Link]]

Comment: You answered part of the question but you didn't address the title question: how do you change the email address on your account? So one way is to open a second account and then request a merger. Is that what you're supposed to do, or is there a more direct solution?

Comment: True, the question title doesn't really match the body. I'll expand the answer.